# The six realms of existence

Tags: personal-practice, realms

Lately, i'm finding myself very confused. I don't know whether i'm trying to learn new things to become a better person for myself and the world around me, or am i in fact just a ' hungry ghost' unable to satisfy my hunger. I do feel like i'm constantly searching for something, something which even i do not know what it looks like.

So, my question is; How can i tell if my efforts are for good, or that of an insatiable hungry ghost?

All help is welcome!

Metta

Comment: Stop learning and start meditating

Comment: So you don't know the answer then Ryan?

Comment: You asked how you could tell if your efforts were good or those of an insatiable ghost. That was my response to your question. And metta to you too :)

Comment: I believe a blind man will never be able to speak of the beautiful colours of a rainbow. My point is, i needed the 4 Noble Truths and my daily meditation to realise ignorance brings pain... i needed the 3 universal characteristics and my meditation to realise the pointlessness of clinging. I'm a believer of the fruit doesn't fall far from the tree, so during meditation i'm introspectively looking for certain characteristics to let me know if my practice is wholesome or not..but the problem is, i can't see the characteristics-the fruit of the tree. So, if i'm blind, no meditation will help me!

Comment: Also, i wish you well and thankyou for your efforts Ryan. Metta.

Comment: If you are practicing insight meditation, that is, seeing things for what they are, this is wholesome. Even if unwholesome things arise: confusion, craving, etc, as long as you see them and know them as they are, this is wholesome. There's nothing wrong with being confused! At the very least, you KNOW you're confused, this is further than most people ever get!

Comment: I know, Ryan, that i can sit in meditation or whenever and repeat the words or label "confusion confusion confusion" but, in Karmic law, there is a root cause to my confusion, i believe if i can see this cause and effect, i will remove my confusion through wisdom. Once the root is uplifted, then ignorance and pain and suffering will cease.

Comment: Actually, Ryan, perhaps my ignorance is impatience. Perhaps i just need to keep doing what i'm doing, and maybe once the mind is still enough, the answers will be shown. Maybe?

Comment: Actually, hahah, confusion isn't the problem, it's the fact that i don't want to be confused, that is causing my pain and suffering!! hahah My pain and suffering is coming from my 'wanting' to not be confused!! haha As if i forgot that simple fact!! haha Thanks for your help. Sometimes i just need to air my views, then clarity sometimes presents itself!! It's a problem not having any Buddhists around me!

Comment: sometimes all you need is some perspective :)

Comment: @LeeHebditch has the confusion passed?

Answer (score 4):

If you are worried that your current karmic existence is, or is related to, that of a hungry ghost you should apply the proper antidote. In this case the proper antidote is practicing/developing the [first paramita : generosity](https://imhouston.wordpress.com/dharma-talks/ginger-clarkson/the-paramitas/first-paramita-generosity/)  Doing such and being aware of your desires and the desires of others can help curb the feeling of constantly searching for some unknown thing.

As for how to know if your efforts are proper, or for good as you say, I'll turn you to the short and sweet lojung saying "Of the two witnesses, hold the principle [one.](http://lojongmindtraining.com/Commentary.aspx?author=3&proverb=18)

Try these things and meditate on them, see if they help, I hope they do. Remember, we all exist in this confusion together, you are not alone in this.